# After using data-binding the fonts(value of dropdown) inside dropdown is not visible

Tags: angular

After using data-binding the value that should appear is not visible.
code :

```
(click)="add({Particulars:Particulars.value}, regForm)"

    <select   name="Particulars" class="btn btn-sm" #Particulars [(ngModel)]="regModel.Particulars" ngModel required>
          <option value="Particulars" >Particulars</option>
          <option value="IBM SPSS 1">IBM SPSS1</option>
          <option value="IBM SPSS 2">IBM SPSS 2</option>
          <option value="IIBM SPSS 3">IBM SPSS 3</option>
          <option value="IBM SPSS 4">IBM SPSS 4</option>
      </select>
```

component.ts file :

```
regModel = new Reg('');
```

.ts file:

```
   export class Reg {
      constructor(

  public Particulars: string = 'Particulars' ,

  ) { }
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZXxH.png)

Comment: may be your regModel.Pariculars is  null

Comment: I have given some value to it like..  " public Particulars: string = 'Particulars' "  Still no changes in dropdown

Comment: regModel={Particulars:'Particulars'} give like this it will work

Comment: That should be given inside typescript right?

Comment: can add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: It is the same code that  I have given

Comment: you are using different value in ts and html check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngselect

Comment: After applying md bootstrap it goes away

Comment: I got it! The thing is that it is in loop.2nd time when it is rendered onclick button it again goes

Comment: okay great happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-selected` like following:

```
<select   name="Particulars" class="btn btn-sm" #Particulars [(ngModel)]="regModel.Particulars" ngModel required>
          <option value="Particulars" ng-selected="'Particulars' == regModel.Particulars">Particulars</option>
          <option value="IBM SPSS 1" ng-selected="'IBM SPSS 1' == regModel.Particulars">IBM SPSS1</option>
          <option value="IBM SPSS 2" ng-selected="'IBM SPSS 2' == regModel.Particulars">IBM SPSS 2</option>
          <option value="IIBM SPSS 3" ng-selected="'IIBM SPSS 3' == regModel.Particulars">IBM SPSS 3</option>
          <option value="IBM SPSS 4" ng-selected="'IBM SPSS 4' == regModel.Particulars">IBM SPSS 4</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: ng-selected can be used in Angular 6?